# viewWillDisappear not called in custom NSViewControllerPresentationAnimator

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm having a simple custom animator in a Cocoa app that I use when presenting new view controllers using the `NSViewControllerPresentationAnimator` protocol. How ever, unless I manually call `viewWillDisappear` when removing the view `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear` is not called on the view controller that is dismissed.

Am I missing something, like I know on iOS you need to tell the system when your transition is complete? Couldn't find anything about that in the protocol documentation.

This is my implementation today and as you see I manually call viewWillDisappear. Why do I need to do that?

```
- (void)animateDismissalOfViewController:(NSViewController *)viewController fromViewController:(NSViewController *)fromViewController {

    NSView *bottomView = fromViewController.view;
    NSView *topView = viewController.view;

    topView.wantsLayer = YES;
    topView.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = NSViewLayerContentsRedrawOnSetNeedsDisplay;

    [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
                context.duration = 0.5;
                bottomView.animator.alphaValue = 1;
                topView.animator.alphaValue = 0;
            }
            completionHandler:^{
                [topView removeFromSuperview];
                [viewController viewWillDisappear];
            }];

}
```

Comment: I can speculate.  I'll delete this if you say it's worthless.   You call `removeFromSuperview` on an `NSView` -- you perhaps need to use `removeFromParentViewController` on the `viewController` `NSViewController`.  The *VC* hierarchy is new in 10.10.  The *view* hierarchy is old as dirt and I doubt it works differently unless you're using parent-child VCs.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `[viewController removeFromParentViewController]`.

You cannot trigger the `NSViewController` life cycle methods by invoking the `NSView` method `removeFromSuperview` on an `NSViewController`'s `view`.  You have to use an `NSViewController` method.